# Cakephp api POST request , saving data without validation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have created a route with Api prefix

```
$routes->scope('/api', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->setExtensions(['json']);
        
        $routes->post(
            '/add-categories',
            ['controller' => 'Miles', 'action' => 'addCategories','prefix'=>'Api']
        );
 }
```

I have created a controller file in directory Controller/Api/MilesController.php

I have created a addCategory method like below

```
    public function addCategories()
    {
            $categoriesTable = $this->fetchTable('Categories');
            $categoryEnt = $categoriesTable->newEmptyEntity();
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $category = $categoriesTable->patchEntity($categoryEnt, $this->request->getData());
                if ($categoriesTable->save($category)) {
                    $responseBody = [
                        'status' => 201,
                        'data' => $category
                    ];
                }else{
                    $responseBody = [
                        'status' => 400,
                        'data' => $category->getErrors()
                    ];
                }
            }
            $this->set(compact('responseBody'));
            $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', ['responseBody']);
   }
```

In postman if I try to send a post request without any data , then I getting the response like below

```
{
    "responseBody": {
        "status": 201,
        "data": {
            "created": "2022-05-10T20:04:13+09:00",
            "modified": "2022-05-10T20:04:13+09:00",
            "id": 8
        }
    }
}
```

My Model/Table/CategoriesTable.php looks  like

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;


class CategoriesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('categories');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Products', [
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        ]);
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
    {
        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('id', null, 'create');

        $validator
            ->scalar('title')
            ->notEmptyString('title');

        $validator
            ->boolean('status')
            ->notEmptyString('status');

        $validator
            ->scalar('imageUrl')
            ->allowEmptyFile('imageUrl');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

Why my notEmptyString validation not working which I have written in `CategoriesTable.php` file ?
Note : This Api/MilesController.php has no self model. How can I apply CategoriesTable validation here ?

Comment: The most relevant part of your code is missing, the validation rules setup.

Comment: @ndm Would you please describe little more or provide me an example ?

Comment: @ndm I have written validation rule in CategoriesTable .

Comment: What I'm saying is that you need to post your validation rules code here too, otherwise nobody can tell if there's something wrong.

Comment: @ndm sorry, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your fields are set as being required, ie they are all optional, and when an optional field is missing, no validation rules will be applied.

So for all fields that must be present, use `requirePresence()`, for example:

```php
$validator
    ->requirePresence('title', 'create') // required on create, optional on update
    ->scalar('title')
    ->notEmptyString('title');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Validation > Creating Validators > Requiring Field Presence](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/validation.html#requiring-field-presence)**